# How to use Gson to store a Pojo file in Mongo DB

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I need to store a POJO file in MongoDB which is stored in my local drive. After doing some research I came to know that using GSON we can achieve this by converting the POJO file to Json.
This is my rest code but I am not getting how to convert the file to Json format.

```
public Response mongoSave() throws ApplicationException {
            BufferedReader br = null;
                try {

                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\frangwala\\Documents\\My Received Files\\ClaimsPartyInfo_.java"));

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                }
                Gson gson=new Gson();
                String json = gson.toJson(br.readLine());//Here I am not getting what should I pass so that the whole file converts into json format which I can save in Mongo DB
                System.out.println(json);
            }
```

Can anyone please suggest how should I convert the whole POJO file to a format which could be save in Mongo DB.

Comment: You don't convert files into JSON. You convert instance of your classes. Please read the Gson documentation

Comment: Can you please suggest should I use GSON or not for saving POJO file to Mongo DB. As I am quite new using Mongo DB.

Comment: I don't think your problem is Mongo at the moment. It's Gson.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using JSON with MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5699323/using-json-with-mongodb)

Comment: Also relevant.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170506/inserting-java-object-to-mongodb-collection-using-java

Comment: Can i save the whole POJO file to MongoDB.? And retrieve it.? As with this links i am not getting one thing whether they are saving the set fields to Mongo or saving the entire file

Comment: Again, you don't save "files"... I don't think you read this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20663686/2308683